# HTTP Requesting data from a local server

Tags: javascript, http, flask, httprequest

I'm running two Flask Apps on my local machine.

1) My test client website (on port 5001)

2) My API (on port 5000)

If I type `127.0.0.1:5000/search/` into my browser, I get the following:

```
Test Hello World
```

If I type `127.0.0.1:5001` into my browser I get an ordinary web page containing the following HTML code (this all looks OK):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo">TEST</p>

<script>

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "127.0.0.1:5000/search/", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the HTTP request is sent to `127.0.0.1:5000/search/` which is tested and working in the browser and should return `Test Hello World` but unfortunately nothing happens.

Basically, I click the "Request Data" button (see above), and absolutely nothing happens.

Any ideas why? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.  For example, XMLHttpRequest follows the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow XMLHttpRequest to make cross-domain requests.

These resources may be helpful;
[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
[Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "127.0.0.1:5000/search/"
> ```

Your URL is missing its scheme. You need to prefix that with `http://`.

If you open your browser's developer tools and look at the Network tab, you should see a 404 error listed there.

---

Once you fix that, it is likely that you'll have a Cross Origin error as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500)